# Change windowsstate of minimized process

Tags: c#

I want my Application to check it's running state. If the program is already running I want it to set it's form to the foregound.

I managed the Program to set the Form into foreground when it's behind a different window. Unfortunately this isn't working when the application is minimized.

```
static void Main()
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Process bProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Name").FirstOrDefault();
            if (bProcess.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                ShowWindow(bProcess.Handle, ShowWindowEnum.ShowNormal);
            }

            SetForegroundWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle); 
    }
```

I tried already a lot of different things but non of them is working.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. You need to grant the other process the [right to set itself to foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow) and then use some form of RPC mechanism to tell *it* to do so.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advice. 
I just realised 'bProcess.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero' changes values suddenly ... sometimes it is 0x00000000 and sometimes it is 0x00230b80. But i did not change the Windowsstate ...
What is a RCP Mechanism ? 
@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: What is the `ShowWindow` method? Shouldn't you pass the window handle instead of the process handle to it? Also note, when the window was maximized before it was minimized, `ShowWindowEnum.ShowNormal` is probably wrong. It should be [SW_RESTORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow). [IsIconic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic) will tell you, if the window is minimized.

Comment: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return:System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowEnum flags);

How would i get window.handle ? 

I tried to us IsIconic but unfortunately this didn't work very well.
Maybe I need to use window.handle here as well.
Here my code: if (!IsIconic(bProcess.Handle))

Comment: You use already `bProcess.MainWindowHandle` one row below in SetForeGroundWindow... ;)

Comment: Also, what is the name of your executable? `GetProcessesByName("Name")` can only find the first instance of your app, if your executable is 'name.exe'. Otherwise you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yeah I know that I use bProcess.MainWindowHandle ... I#m just a little inexperienced in codeing. That's why I assumed bProcess.MainWindowHandle has nothing to do with a Window.handle ... 
I do not get a NullReferenceException ... I assume this is working fine. 
But Is the first instance the one which is already open or the one that is opening right now ?

Comment: Good observation. `Process.GetProcessesByName("Name")` will give you an array with at least 2 elements (first instance and current instance of your app). You'll need to ignore your current process' id which you can get by `Process.GetcurrentProcess().Id`.

Comment: ah ok. So the first instance dosn't have to be the first program(The one which is already open)?

Comment: Exactly. You can't assume that the first element is the first instance of your app.

Comment: `Process bProcess = null;                                                                                    
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();                                        
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Name");                                 
for (int i = 0; i < process.Length; i++)                                                                  
{if (process[i].Id != currentProcess.Id)                                                                  
{bProcess = process[i];}}`

Comment: It looks ok, but try to solve it with LINQ and put it in your answer. Have a look at the extension method [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue ... Thank you guys! This little chat helped a lot!

```
        else
        {
            Process bProcess = null;

            Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Name");
            var LINQprocess = from n in process select n;
            foreach (var item in LINQprocess)
            {
                if (item.Id != currentProcess.Id)
                {
                    bProcess = item;
                }
            }
            if (bProcess != null)
            {
                if (IsIconic(bProcess.MainWindowHandle))
                {
                    ShowWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowEnum.Restore);
                }
            // set user the focus to the window
            SetForegroundWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I will try it iterate the array with LINQ and add it to this answer ... I never heard of this so fare :( 
Thank you very much for your help :) You just made my day ... Hopefully I can help someone out in the future as well and give something back into the community :)